# How to use value of environment variable in project file?

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm trying to add a homebrew library to another project.

Following a suggestion in another answer that I now cannot find, I have created xyz.prf in mkspecs/features and have added

```
    config += xyz
```

to my project file.

xyz.prf contains

```
INCLUDEPATH += $XYZ_INC
DEPENDPATH += $XYZ_INC

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$XYZ_DIR -llibxyz
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$XYZ_DIR -llibxyz
else:unix: LIBS += -L$XYZ_DIR -llibxyz
```

I've defined XYZ_INC and XYZ_DIR in the build configuration and have run qmake as often as needed.

However, when I try to build, there's an error at link time.

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64/lib -o someprogram someprogram.o   -L/home/alan/work/myStuff/sqlPrettyPrinter/v3/build-SQLPPv3-Desktop_Qt_5_12_5_GCC_64bit-Debug/test/test_collationname/../../libsqlpp/ -llibsqlpp -LYZ_DIR -llibxyz /opt/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Test.so /opt/Qt/5.12.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so -lpthread   
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibxyz
```

Now, looking at the g++ command line, I see `-LYZ_DIR` which explains why `ld` can't find libxyz - it ought to be `-L$XYZ_DIR` or `-L<whatever XYZ_DIR expands to>`.

I've tried every combination of `$` or `$$` and `XYZ_DIR`, `{XYZ_DIR}` or `(XYZ_DIR)`. None work and all but the above combination end up generating `-L' (without any directory).

What's the right syntax to generate what I need?

Sorry - this question has ended up longer than intended; however, I can't think of a way that it can sensibly be shortened.

Comment: You say: *I've defined XYZ_INC and XYZ_DIR in the build configuration*, you could explain how you define it.

Comment: I'm using Qt Creator 4.10.1 and have done Projects > Build Environment > Details > Add. I'll see about stitching this into the question and will add a qt-creator tag.

Comment: It is not necessary, I just wanted to be sure that you placed it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#variable-expansion) points out, `$$(...)` must be used to obtain the environment variables:

> Variables can be used to store the contents of environment variables. These can be evaluated at the time when qmake is run, or included in the generated Makefile for evaluation when the project is built.
>
> To obtain the contents of an environment value when qmake is run, use
>   the $$(...) operator:
>
> ```
> DESTDIR = $$(PWD)
> message(The project will be installed in $$DESTDIR)
> ```

**xyz.prf**

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$(XYZ_INC)
DEPENDPATH += $$(XYZ_INC)

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$(XYZ_DIR) -llibxyz
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$(XYZ_DIR) -llibxyz
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$(XYZ_DIR) -llibxyz
```

---

With the previous code element it is applied only when qmake is executed, but if you want it to be executed with the make command you must use `$(...)` as indicated by the docs:

> To obtain the contents of an environment value at the time when the
>   generated Makefile is processed, use the $(...) operator:
>
> ```
> DESTDIR = $$(PWD)
> message(The project will be installed in $$DESTDIR)
>
> DESTDIR = $(PWD)
> message(The project will be installed in the value of PWD)
> message(when the Makefile is processed.)
> ```

**xyz.prf**

```
INCLUDEPATH += $(XYZ_INC)
DEPENDPATH += $(XYZ_INC)

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$(XYZ_DIR) -llibxyz
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$(XYZ_DIR) -llibxyz
else:unix: LIBS += -L$(XYZ_DIR) -llibxyz
```

Comment: I had tried that. It gives a different link-time error; the associated g++ command line includes `... -L  -llibxyz`. To be on the safe side, before testing this, I ran qmake for the whole project (it did nothing) and then did Build > Rebuild All.

Comment: @nurdglaw I have set the environment variables `XYZ_DIR=test_XYZ_DIR` and `XYZ_INC=test_XYZ_INC` as you point out in your comment and when I execute I get `g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../test -I. -Itest_XYZ_INC -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../test/main.cpp` 
`g++  -o test main.o   -Ltest_XYZ_DIR -llibxyz` and as you can see you can see:  `... -Itest_XYZ_INC ...` `... -Ltest_XYZ_DIR ...`(I use Qt 5.14 on Linux)

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried doing something similar. First time around, despite `Build > Clean` and `Build > Rebuild All`, I had my usual error. I then tried `touch`ing my project file and building and it generated the right command line. It seems my underlying problem is not knowing how to ensure that a new Makefile is generated when I fiddle with a `.prf` file. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks again. I had tried that too, but I have another error which I need to resolve before I can tell if this fixes things.

Comment: @nurdglaw I recommend you to test functionalities separately, for example for my test I have created a "hello world" project so you save time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205313/discussion-between-nurdglaw-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. I had a combination of issues, including, but not limited to *) needing to enclose the variable name within round brackets; *) not regenerating the Makefile when testing the effect of a different syntax; *) getting confused and specifying XYZ_INC and XYZ_DIR in the .prf file but defining XYZ_INC and XYZ_LIB in the environment (which caused the error referred to in the chat); and many, many more :-(